как правильно использовать методы setText и getText в библиотеке io.github.iffanmajid:katexmathview
Вот мой класс в котором мне нужно заменить setText и getText на что то другое
public class MessageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private final List<Message> messageList;

public MessageAdapter(List<Message> messageList) {
    this.messageList = messageList;
}


@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View chatView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.chat_item, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(chatView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Message message = messageList.get(position);
    if (message.getSentBy().equals(Message.SEND_BY_ME)) {
        holder.left_chat_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.right_chat_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.right_chat_text_view.setText(message.getMessage());

    } else {
        holder.right_chat_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.left_chat_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.left_chat_math_view.setText(message.getMessage());

        holder.copy_oplata_button.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            copyToClipboard2(holder, holder.text_oplata.getText().toString());
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Скопировано!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        });

        // Обработчик кнопки копирования для сообщений от бота
        holder.copy_left_button.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            copyToClipboard(holder, holder.left_chat_math_view.getText().toString());
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Скопировано!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        });
    }
}

private void copyToClipboard2(MyViewHolder holder, String text) {
    ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) holder.itemView.getContext().getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
    ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("Copied text", text);
    clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
}

// Метод для копирования текста в буфер обмена
private void copyToClipboard(MyViewHolder holder, String text) {
    ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) holder.itemView.getContext().getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
    ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("Copied text", text);
    clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return messageList.size();
}

static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    MaterialCardView left_chat_view, right_chat_view;
    TextView  right_chat_text_view, text_oplata;
    ImageView copy_left_button, copy_oplata_button;
    MathView left_chat_math_view;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        left_chat_view = itemView.findViewById(R.id.left_chat_view);
        right_chat_view = itemView.findViewById(R.id.right_chat_view);
        left_chat_math_view = itemView.findViewById(R.id.left_chat_math_view);
        right_chat_text_view = itemView.findViewById(R.id.right_chat_text_view);

        copy_left_button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.copy_left_button);
        copy_oplata_button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.copy_oplata_button);
        text_oplata = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_oplata);

    }

}

}

Объясните, зачем вам надо заменять эти методы, и на что вы хотите их поменять?

у меня возникает ошибка, потому что я заменил textview на MathView(WebView)

Скорее всего, в классе MathView данной библиотеки отсутствуют методы setText и getText.  Похоже, что её исходный код находится здесь, и в примере использования в файле README.md указано, что следует использовать метод setDisplayText

да, это так, но что использовать вместо getText
